# Calling an isset function in another isset function

Tags: php, mysql

I will ask my question in form of an example. It goes this; I have an index.php where all my posts are, upon clicking on one post it will take me to post.php using the id of the post I clicked on. In the post.php, I have a form for commenting available to all post. The problem now is I want to get specific comments made to a post. I know I can achieve that by getting the post_id coming from index.php to my comment table in database. So please bosses, how can I get the post_id to my comment table.

This is my code down here

```
<?php include "includes/db.php";?>

<!-- Receiving My Comment Form -->
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit_comment'])) {
      $name = $_POST['author'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $comment = $_POST['comment'];
      $date = date('Y-m-d h-i-s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (name, email, post, comment, date, status, 
        post_comment_id) VALUES ('$name', '$email', 'I want to learn PHP', 
        '$comment', '$date', 'unapprove', '$getcommentid')";
$run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CMS SYSTEM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>  
<div class="container">
<article class="row">
<section class="col-lg-8">  
  <!-- Displaying Post coming from Get Super Global from Index.php -->
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
$sel_sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '$_GET[post_id]'";
$run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_sql);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)) {
echo '
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="panel-header">
    <h2>'.$rows['title'].'</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="'.$rows['images'].'" width="50%">
    <p>'.$rows['description'].'</p>
    </div>
    </div> 
    </div>';
}
  } else {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">No post you  selected to show: <a href="index.php">Click Here</a> to see more posts</div>';
  }
?>
<hr>
<!-- Displaying Comments Here -->
<h2><u>Comment Section</u></h2>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
$com_sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE status = 'approved' AND 
            post_comment_id = '$_GET[post_id]'";
$run_com = mysqli_query($conn, $com_sql);
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_com)) {
echo '
      <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="panel-header">
      <h2>'.$result['name'].'</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
      <p>'.$result['date'].'</p>
      <p>'.$result['comment'].'</p>
      </div>
      </div> 
      </div>';
 }
    } else {
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">No post you  selected to show: <a 
         href="index.php">Click Here</a> to see more posts</div>';
}
?>
 <!-- Comment Form -->
<div class="col-lg-10">
<div class="page-header"><h2>Leave A Comment Here</h2></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<form class="form-horizontal col-lg-8" action="post.php" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="" required>Name</label>
<input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="author">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email" class="" required>Your Email Address</label>
<input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="comment" class="">Your Comment Here</label>
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="5" cols="50" tabindex="4" required="required"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" name="submit_comment">
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>   
</section>
<?php include 'includes/sidebar.php'; ?>    
</article>            
</div>
        <div style="width:50px; height:50px;"></div>
    <?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: posting your code will help us to know where you are stuck now, and how should we help you

Comment: firstly, you should really not code things that way, you are supporting "Code injection" and your page would be easily hacked, secondly, I am not sure I understand your data model. I assume you have comments in a separate table because you want to support multiple comments per post, but you're not setting a foreign key (IE post_id), so getting the comments for post might be difficult

Comment: Yes, I have my comment table separately, what I want I how do I get the post_id coming from get url to the comments table

Comment: is the url "post.php?post_id=1234" where 1234 is your post_id ?

Comment: try echoing / var_dump on the $com_sql variable to see what it is set to prior to mysqli_query, I don't think you are getting the right value in that

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, I just wrote it in this comment box, hope  the syntax is correct :)

```
<?php // index.php
 
$posts = {1,2,3,4,5};
foreach( $posts => $post ) {
echo "<a href='post.php?id=" . $post . "' >post number #" . $post . "</a><br>";
}
?>

<?php // post.php
if (isset( $_GET["id"] ) ) {
   $st = $dbpdo->prepare("select * from posttable where id = :id");
   $st->bindParam(':id', $_GET["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $st->execute();
   $result = $st->fetchAll();
   echo "your comment is " .  $result[0]["COMMENT"];
}
?>
```

Comment: The code is helpful to show that I guessed wrong on what you were trying to do, is what you posted all inside the post.php?